# Wesocket mock server for okhttp (android)

Tags: android, testing, websocket, mocking, okhttp

I want to find a normal websocket mock server solution for android UI tests (chat). I've found [this examples](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/f8fd4d08decf697013008b05ad7d2be10a648358/okhttp/src/test/java/okhttp3/internal/ws/WebSocketHttpTest.java)

But I cannot see here the way how reproduce this situation:

1. App sends some message to websocket normally (for example, "RegisterDevice" text).
2. WebServer catching this query to wedsocket and sends some mock answer to the same open socket.

Solution from okHttp just allows to create some separate websocket session and sends some text there, as I understand. But it's not what I want. I need the webserver itself to intercept messages in an already open socket inside the application according to a certain condition. Is it possible?

Comment: Since you are using okHttp, why not just connect to the websocket you describe normally? How are you testing this?

Comment: Cause I need to mock webscoket answers during the test

Comment: And how is that related to the UI? If you want to test how you render the messages, you can just use dummy data. If you want to test your ViewModel, you can just inject a scope instead of using viewModelScope directly so it will run in jUnit. Same thing if you want to test the repository. Or you can just mock those for your test. Ultimately, there's no reason other layers should be aware of how the data comes into the app. A websocket is just a remote data stream, so it should be exposed to other layers as a data stream, which can be mocked if needed.

Comment: And we come back to the question - how to make a mock of a websocket? There are many ways to make an http server mock. With your logic, these libraries are not needed either.

Comment: What we did in our JavaFX project, which has similar requirement, we wrote a mock webserver which is basically a standard websocket/ rest server which listens for incoming local connections. In our test setup we can configure these mock webserver to give expected answers to requests, the webserver has a mockito spy Object inside which can be accessed in the tests and we can check if the expected methods with the expected arguments (data) were called. The mock webserver calls this spy on every receive method with the received arguments. Not sure if an existing solution exists.

Comment: @grill2010 looks the same as I implement. Just mocking okhttpClient  when it creates new connection and mock for client object itself, Unfortunately, I cannot found any solulution like WireMock, for example, when you just need to provide "localhost" url only.